# How do I limit the number of workers in a Playwright Java project?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

I now have a large number of tests that I don't want to run all in parallel, but only a certain number that has yet to be determined. How do I set this in Playwright Java?

Comment: This doesnt make sense. Can you provide extra detail?

Answer (score -1):

I have already found out for myself. It works via Maven by setting the parameter [forkCount](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) in the pom.xml to the desired value.